Oracle constraint stuck in an unusable status
So I have a bit of a pickle.
I have a constraint on a table which is currently in "UNUSABLE" status.  I am trying to get it back to "VALID" status.
The normal way to do this is to use rebuild, ie:
ALTER INDEX PK_1 REBUILD;

but when I try that, I get this error:
ORA-01452: cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate keys found

So then I thought I'd fix it by deleting all the rows in the table that have a duplicate in the key column:
DELETE from TABLE_1
WHERE PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN IN ( SELECT PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN FROM TABLE_1
                              GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN HAVING COUNT(PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN) > 1);

but when I try to do that, I get this error:
ORA-01502: index 'PK_1' or partition of such index is in unusable state.

So in other words, in order to get the constraint out of UNUSABLE state, I have to remove all the duplicate records in the table, but in order to remove all the duplicate records in the table, I have to get the constraint out of UNUSABLE state.
So I'm at a loss.
How can I get my constraint out of the UNUSABLE state and back into VALID state, being that there are duplicate records in the table?

Addition:
I am able to drop the index:
DROP INDEX PK_1

However, that doesn't solve the problem, because I need the index to exist, because I need the constraint on the table to exist.  But I cannot put the constraint back on the table, because the index is in UNUSABLE status:
alter table TABLE_1
add constraint PK_1 primary key(PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN)


You seem to have an index, which may once have been supporting a constraint, but is now orphaned; so you can just drop the index? It may still be linked to a constraint, I suppose, with different names. (Unusual but not impossible). You can look in user_constraints for a row with that index_name to check.

Thank you Alex.  You're right, it's an orphaned index, wow.  Using that information, I am able to drop it.  But then I can't rebuild it, because it is gone.  I'm trying to get the index status changed from UNUSABLE to VALID, not delete it entirely.  Any ideas?

Why can't you drop it and then (after cleaning up the data) recreate it? Either just as an index, or as a primary key (presumably, from the name) constraint?

I am not the original creator and I'm not very confident that I would be able to re-create it correctly.   I was hoping for a way to fix the issue besides the sledgehammer method of delete and re-create.  But since I just deleted it, I don't have any other choice now :|

Just a note, you don't have to delete all duplicate rows. You can remove just the duplicates with DELETE FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM TABLE_1 GROUP BY PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN)

"because I need the index to exist" - hard to believe because you have duplicate rows, and the index is unusable. So, in fact this index is not present.

You can retrieve the correct create command with DBMS_METADATA package. Try SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('INDEX', 'PK_1', USER) FROM dual;

Drop the index, clean the data, and recreate the index. There's no special magic to a primary key.
